# how can I stop the application part of the url being passed to my servlet in tomcat6

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat6

I am running tomcat6 and have hooked it up in eclipse as a server so I can quickly debug code changes - however I am running into an issue with the routes that are passed to my servlet.

I am running spring mvc3 with my routes annotated on the class eg:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/rest")
public class HandleItController {
...
```

in web.xml I have

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>handleit</servletmapping>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However I can only get one of these settings to work as desired at a time.

lets say "Web Project Settings" has Context root set to be `appname`
now if I GET localhost:8080/appname I will get the welcome page as desired
however if I hit localhost:8080/appname/rest/yadda I get a warning saying

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appname/rest/yadda] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'handleit'

If I change my servlet url-pattern to / then I get request routed through the servlet without the appname prepended and the servlet handles them as expected - however I cannot then hit the welcome page

I need a solution that does not involve hard coding `appname` into the web.xml or the controller mappings, there must be some way I can serve both the html file and the servlet that is independent of the uri to which my application is deployed - ie stop sending the context part of the url through to the servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URI in the `@RequestMapping` will be appended to the `url-mapping` of the dispatcher servlet. So if both the servlet and controller is mapped to `rest`, the full URI will become `/contextpath/rest/rest`. If you don't want that, map your controller to `/`

**Edit**: The reason it doesn't work when you map your servlet to `/` is that the Spring dispatcher servlet handles everything under the context root. So to get that to work, you need to configure Spring MVC to serve static files.

Comment: looking at how spring can deal with static files with the controller mapped to / got me on the right path